# IOS connect to PHP webserver insert Data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json, post

I am trying to post a NSDictionary (encoded as Json format) to webserver (handled by php),
in php, i am trying to decode json data and retrieve the variables one by one,
then insert these variables into mysql DB
here are some of my code:

```
    -(void)postTest{

    //build up the request that is to be sent to the server
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/index.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"postValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];

    //create data that will be sent in the post
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictionary setValue:@"p7878" forKey:@"id"];
    [dictionary setValue:@"tmd" forKey:@"first_name"];
    [dictionary setValue:@"nmb" forKey:@"last_name"];
    [dictionary setValue:@"goog" forKey:@"industry"];

    //serialize the dictionary data as json
    NSData *data = [[dictionary copy] JSONValue];

    [request setHTTPBody:data]; //set the data as the post body
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(!connection){
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
    }

}
```

i can see those data are post to webserver successfully. but somehow  i cannot deserilized the json data and stored in different variables on php:

```
 <?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","wenetwork");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_METHOD'] === 'postValues'){ 
   $body;
   /*Sometimes the body data is attached in raw form and is not attached 
   to $_POST, this needs to be handled*/
   if($_POST == null){
      $handle  = fopen('php://input', 'r');
      $rawData = fgets($handle);
      $body = json_decode($rawData);
   }
   else{
      $body == $_POST;
   }



   echo json_encode($body);//just return the post you sent it for testing purposes


    $id = $body['id'];
    $first_name = $body['first_name'];
    $last_name = $body['last_name'];
    $industry = $body['industry'];


    $insertProfile = "INSERT INTO basic_profile (id, first_name, last_name, industry) VALUES ('". $id ."','". $first_name ."','". $last_name ."','". $industry ."')";

    mysqli_query($con, $insertProfile) or die (mysqli_error("Insert item's profile failed"));

    echo "Item added successfully!";
}
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

those $id, $firstname etc. are not able to hold correct data which sent from ios...
therefore, when i excuted the sql statement, it doesn't work...
can someone suggest me with solutions? 
cheers

Comment: BTW, rather than a `HTTP_METHOD` (or `METHOD` ... you use both of these) of `postValues`, I might suggest something more common, such as `Content-Type` of `application/json` or something like that. Also, don't forget to use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to protect yourself against SQL injection attacks and routine errors with values with an apostrophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved by myself, just replace the if statement in php with following...

```
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_METHOD'] === 'postValues'){ 
   $jsonArray;
   /*Sometimes the body data is attached in raw form and is not attached 
   to $_POST, this needs to be handled*/
   if($_POST == null){
      $jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
      $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
   }
   else{
      $jsonArray == $_POST;
   }



   echo json_encode($jsonArray);//just return the post you sent it for testing purposes



    // with [] instead of ()
    $email = $jsonArray['firstkey']; 

    $id = $jsonArray['id'];
    $first_name = $jsonArray['first_name'];
    $last_name = $jsonArray['last_name'];
    $industry = $jsonArray['industry'];


    $insertProfile = "INSERT INTO basic_profile (id, first_name, last_name, industry) VALUES ('". $id ."','". $first_name ."','". $last_name ."','". $industry ."')";

    mysqli_query($con, $insertProfile) or die (mysqli_error("Insert item's profile failed"));

    echo "Item added successfully!";
}
```